# Wordpress Blog Subfolder in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, wordpress, blog, magento-2.2.1

I would like to create a blog using Wordpress and I'd like to have it as a subfolder in Magento domain. Can you let me know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the Fishpig extension for installation of wordpress.
This link to the extension is below:-
https://fishpig.co.uk/magento-2/wordpress-integration/

This is the link on how can you installation steps:-
https://fishpig.co.uk/magento-2/wordpress-integration/installing-wordpress/

You can enable/disable the extension using following commands:-

```
php bin/magento module:enable FishPig_WordPress

php bin/magento module:disable FishPig_WordPress
```

After the installation and clearing cache you will need to run the following command:-

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

The same steps can be seen on the following link as well:-

https://fishpig.co.uk/magento-2/wordpress-integration/installation/

If you want to know more about the commands for Magento2, you can hit the below command in the CLI:-

```
php bin/magento
```

> P.S :-WordPress Database You can install WordPress in the same
>   database as Magento or in a completely separate database. The
>   extension supports both options.

Refer to link:- https://fishpig.co.uk/magento-2/wordpress-integration/installing-wordpress/

Comment: But I don't want to share my magento admin panel credentials with anyone, so I prefer to have them as a separate wordpress login. Can I do that using this?

Comment: You can create a new user from admin, and give it a role of just the Fishpig section.  For that follow this link on how to do so:-
http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/permissions-user-roles.html

Comment: And the Wordpress will act as a separate entity. I suggest you read the documentation shared. It will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [this](https://fishpig.co.uk/magento-2/wordpress-integration/) extension to get this work.

Comment: But I don't want to share my magento admin panel credentials with anyone, so I prefer to have them as a separate wordpress login. Can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

- Download the latest version of Wordpress and upload the zip folder in    your Magento 2 root directory.
- Now extract the archive folder and you will get a folder named    wordpress.
- Then rename the wordpress folder as wp.
- Then install the WordPress by open your store with adding /wp at the of URL like example.com/wp
- Then you have to Download and Install [FishPig Magento WordPress Integration module](https://fishpig.co.uk/magento-2/wordpress-integration/)

Comment: But I don't want to share my magento admin panel credentials with anyone, so I prefer to have them as a separate wordpress login. Can I do that using this?

Comment: Yes, you will login WP admin panel separately like example.com/wp/wp-login.php

Comment: @MuneebSyed Hey after installing fishpig what to do? my blog redirectng me to 404 page?

Comment: Hey, after the installation of module, you have to copy fishpig theme to wp folder and you have to do configuration in your WordPress admin panel. You can check this guide for reference: https://magenticians.com/magento-2-wordpress-integration/